# How does the number of unique user larger than users ? google analytics

Tags: android, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

I am using google analytics campaign tracking with my android app,
i don't understand how unique users (user who download the app just one time) is larger than users (new users and returning users) .
here is a screen shot:
[image]

EDIT , here is my android Code:

Manifest:

```
<!-- Enable Google Play Store Campaign reports -->
        <receiver
            android:name=".analytics.CustomCampaignTrackingReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingService"
            android:enabled="true" />
```

My Custom Receiver:

```
public class CustomCampaignTrackingReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        //get campaign url
        String campaignUrl = intent.getStringExtra("referrer");
       // Log.i("GAThread", "campaign Url:" + campaignUrl);

        SharedStorage.defaultInstance(context).setCampaignTrackingUrl(campaignUrl);

        // When you're done, pass the intent to the Google Analytics receiver.
        new CampaignTrackingReceiver().onReceive(context, intent);
    }
}
```

default tracker:

```
 private Tracker mTracker;

    /**
     * Gets the default {@link Tracker} for this {@link Application}.
     *
     * @return tracker
     */
    synchronized public Tracker getDefaultTracker() {
        if (mTracker == null) {
            GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
            analytics.setLocalDispatchPeriod(5);
            //analytics.getLogger().setLogLevel(Logger.LogLevel.VERBOSE);
            // To enable debug logging use: adb shell setprop log.tag.GAv4 DEBUG
            mTracker = analytics.newTracker("********");
        }

        String userId = Storage.getUserId(this);
        if (userId != null)
            mTracker.set("&uid", userId);

        return mTracker;
    }
```

at onResume and onPause activity i send open & close app event:

```
onResume(){
 getDefaultTracker().send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()
                .setCategory(referrer)//category would be campaign tracking url
                .setAction("openApp")
                .setLabel(userId)
                .build());

}

onPause(){

  getDefaultTracker().send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()
                    .setCategory(referrer)//category would be campaign tracking url
                    .setAction("closeApp")
                    .setLabel(userId)
                    .build());
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't related to coding, and also you've already posted this into the more appropriate Webmaster forum.

Comment: @nyuen there is no problem to ask  a question in tow different forums.

Comment: That's not the problem. Stackoverflow is for coding related questions, and your question is not related to coding.

Comment: Looks like an implementation problem, could you also share the code that you implemented on Android.

Comment: @SamirKumar thank you for your comment, i've edited the question